# How to set the packetbuf_attr value of ICMPv6 packets in contiki?

Tags: contiki, icmp

When I get a ICMPv6 packet from neighbors, such as DIO. I use printf("%u",packetbuf_attr(PACKETBUF_ATTR_TIMESTAMP)), it outputs 0. How can a sender set a value in it and receiver print it?
Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Packetbuf attributes are for communication internal to the node, between network stack layers, not between different nodes. `PACKETBUF_ATTR_TIMESTAMP` and other packet attributes are not directly sent over the network. You should add any timestamps to the payload of the message.